# How can i access the name of the logged in user?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

So i have got a profile page where the user is directed to if he/she is logged in. I want to display the name, birth,picture, etc on the page. But i dont know how to access the name of the user, since i only request the name when the user signs up for my website.

code profile page:

```
const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
    const { loading, userInfo, error } = userLogin
    const [activeProfile, setActiveProfile] = useState(false) 


{userInfo ? (
    active ? (
        <div className="profile-setting">
            <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faTimes}
                className="close-btn-profile"
                size={'2x'}
                onClick={() => alert('closed')}
            />
            <div className="profile-img">
                <img src={img} alt="name" />
            </div>
            <p className="profile-name">{name}</p>
            <p>
                {' '}
                Wishlist
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} />
                <span>0</span>
            </p>
            <button
                className="logout-btn"
                onClick={() => alert('logged out')}
            >
                Logout
            </button>
        </div>
    ) : (
        <div
            className="profile-btn"
            onClick={setActive(true)}
        >
            <img src={img} />
        </div>
    )
) : (
    <Link to="/login">
        <li>Login</li>
    </Link>
)}
```

code Register reducer:

```
function userRegisterReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.USER_REGISTER_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true }
        case actions.USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload }
        case actions.USER_REGISTER_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

code register action:

```
const register = (name, email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: actions.USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,
        payload: {
            name,
            email,
            password,
        },
    })
    try {
        const { data } = await Axios.post(
            'http://localhost:5000/users/register',
            {
                name,
                email,
                password,
            }
        )
        dispatch({ type: actions.USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: data })
        Cookie.set('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: actions.USER_REGISTER_FAIL, payload: error.message })
    }
}
```

code Login action:

```
const login = (email, password, name) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: actions.USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
        payload: {
            email,
            password,
            name,
        },
    })
    try {
        const { data } = await Axios.post(
            'http://localhost:5000/users/signin',
            { email, password, name }
        )
        dispatch({ type: actions.USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data })
        Cookie.set('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: actions.USER_LOGIN_FAIL, payload: error.message })
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume all of these that you want to display are in `userInfo`, which should come from the backend to the state. Extract them from `userInfo` as `const {name, ...etc} = userInfo`

Comment: @BlackMath do i need to pull it from the register action or the login action ?

Comment: It's in the state, and you are pulling it in the profile component using `useSelector`. Wherever you want to use name use `userInfo.name` and wherever you want to use the image use `userInfo.img` ... etc.

Comment: i am so stupid, thanks @BlackMath

Comment: You are not. You are learning.